# Estimate the derivative doing the limit in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want write a script in MATLAB that computes the quotient of the derivative (f(x+h)-f(x))/h for the function x^2 at x=2 and h starting at 1 and decreasing by a factor of 10, and the book said that the effect of the rounding error becomes apparent when h gets to small (less than 10^-12).

Then I wrote the following code:

```
for i=0:-2:-16
    h=10^i;
    ((2+h)^2-(2)^2)./h
end
```

Then my question is, How can I improve my code? because It gives me indeed an error saying that the last approximation to the derivative is zero.

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: You can start by **not** using i as a variable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab

Comment: I am sorry I have moved my question to code review because The thing is that I want a verification :) Thanks

Comment: In code review told me that I have to verify my code here :) what can be done then ?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the limit of floating point arithmetic you are limited in how small you can choose `h`. An reasonable option for choosing a "safe" small `h` is using `h=x*sqrt(eps)` where `eps` is the distance from 1.0 to the next largest double-precision number, that is, `eps = 2^-52`

This Wikipedia page contains some more [information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation#Practical_considerations_using_floating_point_arithmetic)

If you REALLY wanted higher precision arithmetic you could consider using an implementation of multi-precision arithmetic. For example [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6446-multiple-precision-toolbox-for-matlab) is a MATLAB wrapper around the well-established [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) (GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library)  and [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/) (multiple-precision floating-point computations with exact rounding)

Comment: Thanks a lot, the thing is that I don't want to fix the error I want a verification of my code, If my code is right or someone that knows what to expect that tell that my code is doing the things right :)

Comment: looks right. In fact if you develop your expression

y = ((x+h)^2-(x)^2)./h = (x^2 + 2*h*x + h^2 - x^2) / h = 2*x + h -> When h is small y=2x  which is the derivative of x^2, and is 4 at x=2

Comment: Thnks :), but what do you mean by "If you develop your expression"?

Comment: Right :) then my code is indeed having a rounding error when I less than 10^-12 right?

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, That is what I was searching for, a verification, that someone could tell me if it was right or I was missing something and how to fix it :)